# Flutter - there is an unknown black AppBar when entering landscape fullscreen mode on iOS Device

Tags: flutter

there is an unknown black AppBar when entering landscape fullscreen mode on iOS Device

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxU94.jpg)

Just want to figure out why there is a black bar

I'm pretty sure that youtube player doesn't matter if youtube player were removed

Code Snippet

```
{
late YoutubePlayerController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
    
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: widget.stream,
        flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(autoPlay: true, isLive: true));
    
    @override dispose() {
             SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,]);
            super.dispose(); 
    } 
    
    @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Stack(children: [
            YoutubePlayerBuilder(player: YoutubePlayer(controller: _controller,),builder: (context, player) {
              return Column(children: [player,],);
     })
    ]);
    }}
```

flutter doctor info are as below:
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.3, on macOS 13.5 22G5038d darwin-arm64, locale zh-Hant-TW)
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)

Just want to figure out why there is a black bar
and how to fix it

Flutter - there is an unknown black AppBar when entering landscape fullscreen mode on iOS Device